# Any way to check whether a function has external side-effects (or enforce that it won't)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, constants, immutability

I am interested in Javascript frameworks like [Rivertrail](https://github.com/RiverTrail/RiverTrail), which provides a parallel programming abstraction, but only provides well defined semantics if the functions you pass in to do the work have [no external side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

I'm wondering if there is any way to either write a check that a passed in function is side-effect free? or to hide everything in the environment from a function (so that it has nothing to modify)? or temporarily declare everything in the environment "const" (but just for the scope of the definition of the function?)  (Or any other crazy idea that would give me the equivalent of simply declaring `__attribute__ ((pure))` in gcc.)

Parallel programming is one of those places where "pure" functional programming can really make a difference.  Without pure functions defining reasonable semantics for parallel programs gets really hard (check out the semantics of C++ where they had to define what a *data-race* is so that they could declare that any program that has one is undefined.)

I can imagine other places where someone might find this useful, if it were possible.  It might be useful to allow users of a web-page to pass in guaranteed pure no-side-effect Javascript functions that check for certain conditions during a query, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> write a check that a passed in function is side-effect free?

This is ["effect analysis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system) - a form of type checking.

Since Javascript doesn't have a type and effect system, any approach to detecting side effects will necessarily be approximate and rely on heuristics. There's no way to do this in general for Javascript.